# Why state is not getting updated here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Button = () => {

    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    const btnRef = useRef();


    useEffect(() => {
        btnRef.current.addEventListener('click', function () {
            setCounter(counter => 1);
            console.log('counter ', counter);
        })
    },[])

    return (
        <button ref={btnRef}>Click Me</button>
    )
}

export default Button;
```

On each click of button, console shows only '0', why setCounter is not updating the state here ?

Comment: state is updated asynchronously and it is constant within a particular render of a component. So using the state value right after calling the state setter function will give you the old state. Component has to re-render before it can see the updated state. You also have a problem because of closure of the event listener function over the initial value of the `counter` state

Comment: Also note that your code is more complicated than it needs to be. You don't need a ref or useEffect just to add a click event listener on a button.

Comment: In that case, only first time it should show '0', after setCounter runs, component gets re-rendered, now state value has been changed. But in next clicks also, state value appears as the same '0'.

Comment: @Yousaf, it logs `0` on subsequent clicks also. I personally would expect it be 1 after the first click

Comment: @user3760959 read my first comment. It logs 0 because of closure.

Comment: @OleksandrKovalenko it always logs 0 because of closure.

Comment: @Yousaf Yes. that I know, I am experimenting with React refs. It just made me confused about the state and re-rendering, that's why posted here.

Comment: @user3760959 — "component gets re-rendered" – The event handler function is created inside a `useEffect` which has a dependency of `[]` so it only runs on the initial render at which point it locks the *original* `counter` const (with the original value) into a closure.

Comment: You can solve the problem by setting up a new listener everytime counter state changes and also don't forget to clear the previous listener using the cleanup function of the `useEffect` hook

Comment: See [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-fog-75pcv?file=/src/App.js:0-580)

Answer (score -2):

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Button = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const btnRef = useRef();

  console.log(counter)

  useEffect(() => {
    btnRef.current.addEventListener("click", function () {
      setCounter((counter) => 1);
    });
  }, []);

  return <button ref={btnRef}>Click Me</button>;
};
```

Thanks to @Yousaf for explaining the closure issue in comments:

> You also have a problem because of closure of the event listener function over the initial value of the counter state

Comment: So what exactly does your answer provide except for an attribution to a commenter for pointing out the issue? Moving the console log with no explanation? I don't think this has enough substance to be worth answering..

Comment: @BrianThompson this code behaves as original author wanted it to behave: it logs `0`, then `1` instead of always logging `0`

Comment: A good answer should have more than just a block of code, even if that code is corrected. You should at the very least explain *in the answer* what you've done different. Preferably , it should also include **why** you made the changes you did.

Comment: I know the reason for **why** might be in the comments, but answers should be able to stand on their own. This is why SO doesn't allow answers that contain only links. Just like links that go bad, comments are much less permanent than answers, and it may not be around to help future readers.

Comment: @BrianThompson, Yousaf has already explained everything very well. I didn't a reason to copy-paste the comment in the answer.